# Read specific line out of String

Tags: java, string

I have a String that looks like this:

```
String meta = "1 \n"
    + "Herst \n"
    + "01 Jan 2019 – 31 Dec 2020 \n"
    + "01 Jan 2020 \n"
    + "CONFIG \n"
    + "XML \n"
    + "AES \n"
    + "RSA \n"
    + "256 \n"
    + "16 \n"
    + "128 \n";
```

What is the smartest way if I want to read a specific line out of this String in Java?

For example, I need in another part of my code the number of the second last line (in this case it's 16). How can I read this number out of the String?

Comment: [Read String line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096621/read-string-line-by-line)

Comment: [How to get numbers out of string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272575/how-to-get-numbers-out-of-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's already in String form, just split it into lines using `\n` as a delimiter to get an array of lines:

```
String[] lines = meta.split("\n");
```

Then you can easily get a specific line. For instance, `System.out.println(lines[9])` will print `16`.

If you need the `16` in the form of an `int`, you'd need to remove the whitespaces around it, and parse it:

`int parsed = Integer.parseInt(lines[9].trim());`

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I have looked for!